# Gridview not filling body in landscape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using building a view that needs to be responsive on both landscape and  portrait modes, I am using a gridview when I change to landscape however when in landscape the gridview doesnt fill the entire body

Gridview doesn't seem to have a default padding or anything

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSZP.gif)
[In App Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xtuw.gif)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
  ]);
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double height;
   final key =  GlobalKey();

  @override
  initState() {
    //calling the getHeight Function after the Layout is Rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getHeight());

    super.initState();
  }

  getHeight() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final size = renderBoxRed.size.height;
    print("SIZE of container: $size");
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          height = constraints.maxHeight;
          return (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 600 &&
                  MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape)
              ? GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: height,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      key: key,
                      height: height,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: buildChildren(),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: height / 2,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      key: key,
                      height: height / 2,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: buildChildren(),
                    )
                  ],
                );
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    );
  }

  buildChildren() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Body height: " + height.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape ? Text(
            "Container height: " + 640.0.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ) : Text(
            "Container height: " + 576.0.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Device height: " + MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the minimal code needed to reproduce this issue the expected output is the black containers take up the entire available screen real estate, so that none of the scaffold background color is visible. Any help is appreciated.

My goal is to get an Image to fill the entire black container which should fill the entire body in landscape mode on all tablets I am testing on the nexus 10 emu

Comment: Hi, I'm curious what device are you using, is it a real device or an emulator (android)  / simulator (iOS)?

Comment: @JoshuadeGuzman I am primarily testing on an android emu (Nexus 10)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clear, In landscape, only black will show. 
emulator is slow and I have to push button to let emulator know I change to landscape

Edit I have edit my full code, In image part, you need

```
FittedBox(
          child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/bg.jpg',
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
         ))
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
  ]);
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double height;
  double width;
  final key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  initState() {
    //calling the getHeight Function after the Layout is Rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getHeight());

    super.initState();
  }

  getHeight() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final size = renderBoxRed.size.height;
    print("SIZE of container: $size");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          height = constraints.maxHeight;
          width  = constraints.maxWidth;
          return (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 600 &&
                  MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape)
              ? GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: height,
                        width: width / 2,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/bg.jpg',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      key: key,
                      height: height,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: buildChildren(),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        height: height / 2,
                        width: width ,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/bg.jpg',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      key: key,
                      height: height / 2,
                      width: width ,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: buildChildren(),
                    )
                  ],
                );
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    );
  }

  buildChildren() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Body height: " + height.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape
              ? Text(
                  "Container height: " + 640.0.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                )
              : Text(
                  "Container height: " + 576.0.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Device height: " + MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have an image to show what I experience on my emu. In my application I am only allowing rotation on tablet devices i.e. >600 and I need to have an image take up the height and half the width of the device in landscape, but when I set the image I have a 32px overflow on the bottom and a the gap beneath on smaller tablets the image is larger than the screen height It needs to take up the screen height and no more.

Comment: I see you have change your code. could you post your image too

Comment: I have changed my code and add some images to the post

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to resolve my issue. The issue doesn't involve images (which is why I didn't include it in the code) it seems to be something with the gridview as it affects both widgets the container height in the landscape mode is 32px less than the body height

Comment: I did not encounter this case. could you share it on github?

Comment: presuming you mean the flutter repo?  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39022